# how to define common routes or subsequent routes in moustache / ring

Tags: clojure, ring

I have two moustache routes basically the *http://localhost* and *http:localhost/* route which point to the same function -

```
[""]  (-> (index) response constantly)
["/"] (-> (index) response constantly)
```

How do I -

1. Is it possible to specify both of these routes together such as
   ["" "/"] as they follow each other ?
2. Is it possible to redirect from one route to the other ex [""]
   (redirect "/") ?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 0):

the route is a handler, is just a function. and you can use `ring.util.response/redirect`